# Call PHP script from .Net application

Tags: .net, php

Is there anyway to call PHP script from a .Net application and pass in some parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it through a command line call

```
php your-file.php parameter1 parameter2
```

The parameters are available in the `$_SERVER['argv']` variable.

Answer (score 3):

I've got interop with .NET and PHP using web services. You can output XML from both, which means you can call each way.

Comment: Yeh this is very easy to just do a post with content type application/xml.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the PHP runtime installed you can still launch a new process to execute the script.

Have a look at the **Process** class.